# How to use pig in Visual Studio with Azure Hdinsight

Tags: apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I created my HDInsight on Azure and connected with cloud explorer on VS2017.

I want to make a word counter using Hdinsight pig.

I created my pig project but when I start my `script.pig` I get an error:

```
Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\Pig" because it was not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio supports creating and submit Pig scripts to HDInsight clusters. Users can create a Pig project from template, and then submit the script to HDInsight clusters.

After creating a script, if you click on the start button, you will get this error message:

**Could not copy the file "obj\Debug\Pig" because it was not found.**

[image]

You need to submit the pig script to the HDInsight cluster you have created.

[image]

Successfully submitted the pig script to the HDInsight cluster:

[image]